# How Would I Add A Second Google Map Marker Using This Script?

Tags: google-maps

This is the code below. I can't figure out how to add a second marker, I've been toying with it for awhile but I'm terrible with javascript and I really can't figure it out!

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
initializeGoogleMap();

});

// Call this function when the page has been loaded
function initializeGoogleMap() {
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(45.93986,-85.65181);
var myOptions = {
    zoom: 12,
    center: myLatlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("google-map-location"), myOptions);

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatlng,
    map: map
});

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var myLatlng2 = new google.maps.LatLng(45.9,-85.6);

var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatlng2,
    map: map
});
```

or

```
var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(45.9,-85.6),
    map: map
});
```