# Using Google Maps with 2 markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps

This code shows me a Google Map with 1 marker:

```
var myCenter=new google.maps.LatLng(47.406466,8.5505948);
function initialize() {
    var roadAtlasStyles = [{
        "featureType": "road.highway",
        "elementType": "geometry",
        "stylers": [
            { "saturation": -100 },
            { "lightness": -8 },
            { "gamma": 1.18 }
        ]
    }, {
        "featureType": "road.arterial",
        "elementType": "geometry",
        "stylers": [
            { "saturation": -100 },
            { "gamma": 1 },
            { "lightness": -24 }
        ]
    }, {
        "featureType": "poi",
        "elementType": "geometry",
        "stylers": [
            { "saturation": -100 }
        ]
    }, {
        "featureType": "administrative",
        "stylers": [
            { "saturation": -100 }
        ]
    }, {
        "featureType": "transit",
        "stylers": [
            { "saturation": -100 }
        ]
    }, {
        "featureType": "water",
        "elementType": "geometry.fill",
        "stylers": [
            { "saturation": -100 }
        ]
    }, {
        "featureType": "road",
        "stylers": [
            { "saturation": -100 }
        ]
    }, {
        "featureType": "administrative",
        "stylers": [
            { "saturation": -100 }
        ]
    }, {
        "featureType": "landscape",
        "stylers": [
            { "saturation": -100 }
        ]
    }, {
        "featureType": "poi",
        "stylers": [
            { "saturation": -100 }
        ]
    }, 
    {}
    ]

    var mapstyle = [{"stylers": [{ "saturation": -100 },{ "gamma": 1.33 }]}];
    var mapProp = {
        center:myCenter,
        zoom:15,
        styles: mapstyle,
        mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);
    var marker=new google.maps.Marker({
        position:myCenter,
        icon:'http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=%E2%80%A2|ed0e1b'
    });

    marker.setMap(map);
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content:"Geiger AG - Büro und Werkhof<br>Fälmisstrasse 15<br>8833 Samstagern"
    });
    infowindow.open(map,marker,roadAtlasStyles);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

I would like to display another marker which includes another address. Since I have some custom styles on it, I would like to keep the same code but just insert another marker. How can I do this when I want to keep my own code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Maps add new marker and pop up title](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32284507/google-maps-add-new-marker-and-pop-up-title)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How Would I Add A Second Google Map Marker Using This Script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18487060/how-would-i-add-a-second-google-map-marker-using-this-script)

Answer (score 0):

Not really the cleanest way but this is how I resolved it:

```
var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(47.190627,8.6786925);
        var myOtherCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(47.2296871,8.6718189);

        function initialize() {

        var roadAtlasStyles = [
  {
      "featureType": "road.highway",
      "elementType": "geometry",
      "stylers": [
        { "saturation": -100 },
        { "lightness": -8 },
        { "gamma": 1.18 }
      ]
  }, {
      "featureType": "road.arterial",
      "elementType": "geometry",
      "stylers": [
        { "saturation": -100 },
        { "gamma": 1 },
        { "lightness": -24 }
      ]
  }, {
      "featureType": "poi",
      "elementType": "geometry",
      "stylers": [
        { "saturation": -100 }
      ]
  }, {
      "featureType": "administrative",
      "stylers": [
        { "saturation": -100 }
      ]
  }, {
      "featureType": "transit",
      "stylers": [
        { "saturation": -100 }
      ]
  }, {
      "featureType": "water",
      "elementType": "geometry.fill",
      "stylers": [
        { "saturation": -100 }
      ]
  }, {
      "featureType": "road",
      "stylers": [
        { "saturation": -100 }
      ]
  }, {
      "featureType": "administrative",
      "stylers": [
        { "saturation": -100 }
      ]
  }, {
      "featureType": "landscape",
      "stylers": [
        { "saturation": -100 }
      ]
  }, {
      "featureType": "poi",
      "stylers": [
        { "saturation": -100 }
      ]
  }, {
  }
            ]

        var mapstyle = [{"stylers": [{ "saturation": -100 },{ "gamma": 1.33 }]}];
        var mapProp = {
                center:myCenter,
                zoom:12,
                styles: mapstyle,
                mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            var mapProp1 = {
                center:myOtherCenter,
                zoom:12,
                styles: mapstyle,
                mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };

            var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);
            var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp1);

            var marker=new google.maps.Marker({
                  position:myCenter,
                  icon:'http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=%E2%80%A2|ed0e1b'
              });
            var marker1=new google.maps.Marker({
                  position:myOtherCenter,
                  icon:'http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=%E2%80%A2|ed0e1b'
              });

            marker.setMap(map);
            marker1.setMap(map);

            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content:"Geiger AG - Büro und Werkhof<br>Fälmisstrasse 15<br>8833 Samstagern"
             });
            var infowindow1 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content:"Geiger AG - Postadresse<br>Postfach<br>8820 Wädenswil"
             });
            infowindow.open(map,marker,roadAtlasStyles);
            infowindow1.open(map,marker1,roadAtlasStyles);
        }

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: You don't need to redefine the `map` variable.

Answer (score 0):

I cleaned a little also I created a function to create the `addMarker`, if you want to add more markers just add into the `markersData` array and thats it :), maybe you want to add different icons, just add it into `markersData` array

```
(function(){

    var map;
    var mapslatlng = {lat: 47.406466, lng: 8.5505948};
    var markers = [];
    var markersData = [
        ['marker 1', 47.406466, 8.5505948],
        ['marker 2', 47.406466, 8.5565948]
    ];

    function initialize() {

        var mapOptions = { 
            center: mapslatlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN,
            zoom: 15
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapDiv'), mapOptions);

        mapStyle();
        addMarker();
    }

    function mapStyle() {
        var usRoadMapType = new google.maps.StyledMapType([
            {
                "featureType": "road.highway",
                "elementType": "geometry",
                "stylers": [
                    { "saturation": -100 },
                    { "lightness": -8 },
                    { "gamma": 1.18 }
                ]
            }, {
                "featureType": "road.arterial",
                "elementType": "geometry",
                "stylers": [
                    { "saturation": -100 },
                    { "gamma": 1 },
                    { "lightness": -24 }
                ]
            }, {
                "featureType": "poi",
                "elementType": "geometry",
                "stylers": [
                    { "saturation": -100 }
                ]
            }, {
                "featureType": "administrative",
                "stylers": [
                    { "saturation": -100 }
                ]
            }, {
                "featureType": "transit",
                "stylers": [
                    { "saturation": -100 }
                ]
            }, {
                "featureType": "water",
                "elementType": "geometry.fill",
                "stylers": [
                    { "saturation": -100 }
                ]
            }, {
                "featureType": "road",
                "stylers": [
                    { "saturation": -100 }
                ]
            }, {
                "featureType": "administrative",
                "stylers": [
                    { "saturation": -100 }
                ]
            }, {
                "featureType": "landscape",
                "stylers": [
                    { "saturation": -100 }
                ]
            }, {
                "featureType": "poi",
                "stylers": [
                    { "saturation": -100 }
                ]
            }
        ], {name: 'Road Atlas'});
        map.mapTypes.set('usroadatlas', usRoadMapType);
        map.setMapTypeId('usroadatlas');
    }

    function addMarker() {
        for (var i = 0; i < markersData.length; i++) {
            var marker = markersData[i];
            markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
                position: {lat: marker[1], lng: marker[2]},
                title: marker[0],
                map: map,
                draggable: true
            }));
        };

    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

})();
```